# bootstrap dropdown using ul li elements not working

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<ul>
   <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Select <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul name="lstAddresses" class="dropdown-menu selectList__select js-address-list" role="menu">
       <li value="0" selected="selected">address 1</li>
       <li value="1">address 2</li>
       ...........
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

when first loaded, the dropdown is expanded. pressing the caret doesn't toggle the dropdown as I'd expect. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged with c#?

Comment: because it's part of an MVC razor view, so C# users may have also used this technique, who may be able to help

Comment: please add snippet

Comment: @HardikMasalawala ??? snippet is in the question

Comment: any error in console.do you have any other css in page which might effecting. bcz  same code work in here i paste your code. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu&stacked=h

Comment: @JayneshSharma no errors in the console (Chrome) nothing I can find that might effect it.

Comment: @JayneshSharma interesting, my code above wasn't exactly as per your example, but changing my code so that it was, still hasn't made any difference. list opens expanded and it doesn't toggle

Comment: @bilpor  which version of bootstrap u are using ? see here its work i used cdn and  your html 
https://jsfiddle.net/c8jr4y3b/2/

Comment: @JayneshSharma Thanks for your help. I found out that where I am, they have customised bootstrap so that they only load parts that were needed. All of this bit they commented out. Putting it all back in worked.